# How to ensure integrity of encrypted data having hashes only?

Tags: encryption, hash

Having:

1. plaintext $P$
2. a hash function $H$, encryption $E$ with key $k$
3. $h_p = H(P)$ and $h_{E_P} = H(E_k(P))$

Is there an encryption scheme $E$ or hash algorithm $H$ that allows proving that $h_{E_P}$ represents the same plaintext $P$ (but encrypted) without knowing $P$ itself?

In my transmission scheme, there is a trusted Broker for plaintext metadata   (i.e. doesn't have the $P$ itself, but $(h_p, h_{E_P}, k)$ and I want it to "be sure" that the $K$ was really used for encrypting plaintext $P$.

Comment: I've edited your question into MathJax/Latex, please make sure that everything is correct. And note that the title and last paragraph doesn't match.

Comment: Besides Zero-knowledge proofs, that can prove any property of the ciphertext and plaintext (including the one you asked for), there exists options like "fast message franking" - https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016